# How is the Java compiler able to distinguish between those two constructors/methods?

Tags: java, variadic-functions, ambiguous

```java
public class MyClass {

    private String string;
    private Object[] objects;

    // constructor 1
    public MyClass(String string, Object... objects) {
        this.string = string;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    // constructor 2
    public MyClass(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass("foobar");
    }

}
```

In that case, how did the Java compiler decide to use `constructor 2` instead of `constructor 1`? Why no `The constructor ... is ambiguous` or a similar error occurs?

PS: the question works with *classic methods* too.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023439

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's always the most specific method that is called.**

```
new MyClass("foobar");
```

searches to call that constructor which takes an object of type `String` as it's only argument.

and, `var-args` method will be used iff matching `non-var-args` method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

A *var-args* method/constructor will be chosen **only if** there is no *non-var-arg* method/constructor. So it is clear that why compiler chooses `MyClass(String string)`.

Comment: This isn't true for all cases, see this snippet from [JLS 15.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2): _For example, declaring m(Object...) in a class which already declares m(Object) causes m(Object) to no longer be chosen for some invocation expressions (such as m(null)), as m(Object[]) is more specific._

Comment: Throw in auto-(un)boxing for some more confusion... Method resolution has become tricky since Java 5.  I think the cases @Keppil mentions result in a compiler warning at least.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand varargs constructors and methods are only syntax sugar, which transforms to array declarations. So your constructor 1 during compilation would be nearly equal to:

```
public MyClass(String string, Object[] objects) {
    this.string = string;
    this.objects = objects;
}
```

It means, that if you want to construct instance of `MyClass` by following code:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass("Hello", "1", "2");
```

It would be equal to:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass("Hello", new Object[]{"1", "2"} );
```

Comment: Not really equal, because that constructor would not match the call (whereas the varargs one does, just with a lower priority).

Comment: @ Thilo, yes, you're right. I've just wanted to explain concept on example, but couldn't found better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM will look for Exact matching for passing values to variables in methods/constructor, **if it's not able find exact match it will treat the values as Object.**

Answer (score 0):

[jls-15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) states that compiler will first look **best match** for without autoboxing or var agrs. `Constructor #2` fits in your case.

If it had not been there, the first autoboxing will be applied, i.e. any method with parameter super class of String i.e. Object will be callled.

```
   // constructor 2
    public MyClass(Object string) {
        this.string = string.toString();
    }
```

Now, even after applying autoboxing, compiler is not able to find best match, it will go for var args. So, if you remove constructor 2 from your code, first constructor will be called.